# How to display HTML formatted content in to label using C# WinForm?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using C# WinForms.

I want to display HTML formatted content in a Label control. Is it possible to do this? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A label is not meant to display formatted text. You can apply only one format to a label, which will be applied to the whole string.

If you want to display HTML-formatted text in a Windows Forms form, you'd better use a WebBrowser control instead of a label.

Source : http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1121356/Display-HTML-formatted-string-in-to-label

Comment: I am also use web browser control but web browser control does not set auto size property in win forms.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this but with correct approach

either use

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
```

or can

try

```
<asp:Literals>
```

Comment: This question is about Windows Forms, not ASP.NET.